# Template loop in Wikipedia modules

Tags: lua, mediawiki, wikipedia, mediawiki-extensions, mediawiki-templates

I've imported Module:Documentation and Module:Arguments for custom mediawiki from wikipedia. Unfortunately, Lua indicates template loop inside them on also wiki-native pages like Template:Extension, these are not custom templates or pages. Would like a hint or direction to look into, maybe someone encountered the same problem.
[image: callstack]
[image: Template extension]

Comment: Sprinkle `mw.log` here and there?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in Template:Extension docs (probably, Template:Extension/doc). The Module:Documentation in both Russian and English Wikipedias is shorter than 464 lines, so your version is either obsolete or modified.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module:Documentation
Maybe I'm looking at a wrong page, here it has 1000 lines of code

Comment: Is the wiki public? Can you give a link to the errorous page? If not, can you provide the relevant part of the Wikitext and the `?action=raw&templates=expand` of the page?